# How to convert py script with input parameters to exe, and call the exe in another py script

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm new to Python. In order to run the py script1 referenced some third-part libraries in a system without these libraties, I tried to convert the py to exe by pyinstaller, and call the exe in another py script2, the codes are probably look like this:

script1:

```
def func(x):
    c = sum(x)
    print(c)
```

I ran

```bash
pyinstaller -F -w script1.py  -->script1.exe
```

script2:

```
impose subprocess
x = [1,2,3]
subprocess.run([r"...\script1.exe",x])
```

The codes above failed to work. I guess the problem is in the parameters transfer, I found the `sys.argv[]` transfer method, but it seems can't solve my problem either.

Comment: the `...` is that a typo?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: `run()` needs flat list `[r"...\script1.exe", 1, 2, 3]` but you create nested list `[r"...\script1.exe", [1,2,3] ]`. You should do `[r"...\script1.exe"] + x`

Comment: what means `"failed to work"`? We can't read in your mind, and don't expect that we will run code to see problem (besides code may work correctly on our computers). You have to describe all details in question (not in comments).

Comment: to send values to script you have to use execute function with `func( sys.argv[1:] )`. it skips first value which is program's name. But first you should test your code with arguments before you convert to .exe - like `python script1.py 1 2 3`. If this will not work then .exe also will not work. It looks like you create `script1.py only with definion of `func()` but without execution `func( sys.argv[1:] )` - and this will NOT work as .exe. It works only if you `import script1` to other script and execute `func()` in other script

Comment: and one important think: `sys.argv` gets all values as strings so you have to use `int()` to convert every value to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run `.exe` with parameters then you have to

- use `sys.argv` to get parameters but you have to skip first element which is name of your program - `sys.argv[1:]`
- convert all values to `int()` because it can send values only as string
- run your function with parameters `func(values)

```
import sys

def func(x):
    c = sum(x)
    print(c)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    values = []
    
    for item in sys.argv[1:]:
        values.append( int(item) )
        
    func(values)
```

---

Before you convert to `.exe` you should test your code

```
python.exe script1.py 1 2 3
```

---

And when you execute it then you have to use flat list with strings (because it can send only strings)

```
run( [r"...\script1.exe", '1', '2', '3'] )
```

but you have nested list, and this list has integer values

```
run( [r"...\script1.exe", [1, 2, 3] ] )
```

So you need something like this

```
import subprocess

x = [1, 2, 3]

items = []

for value in x:
    items.append( str(value) )

# add two lists to create one flat list
subprocess.run( [r"...\script1.exe"] + items )
```

---

You can reduce code using `list comprehension` or `map()`

```
import sys

def func(x):
    c = sum(x)
    print(c)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    values = [int(item) for item in sys.argv[1:] ]
    #values = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))
        
    func(values)
```

and

```
import subprocess

x = [1, 2, 3]

items = [str(value) for value in x]
#items = list(map(str, x))

subprocess.run( [r"...\script1.exe"] + items )
```

---

**EDIT:**

`func()` has to use `print()` to send result back to first script.

And first script has to capture output (`stdout`)

```
process = subprocess.run( [r"...\script1.exe"] + items, capture_output=True)

text = process.stdout.decode()
result = int( text )

print(result)
```

Comment: The code run successfully. Thanks for your detailed instructions, that really help me. I have one more question, how can I get the returned value from the exe, I added `return c` in def func, and tried to get c through `c = sub.process.run()` in script2, but the returned value is `CompletedProcess(args=['...\\script1.exe', '1', '2', '3'], returncode=0)`, so what's the problem? Thanks for your help again!

Comment: processes can use only strings and `stdout`, `stdin` to communicate - you have to use `print(c)` to send back. And `result = subprocess.run(..., capture_output=True).stdout`. And you get string with number and you may need convert to `int()`

Comment: I add exanple code to answer.